# Cannot access elements within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access elements within an associative array.  However, I do not seem to be able to get to the elements.  If I use `print_r()` it says that is IS an array and shows me what is contained within it.  However, `is_array()` returns false.  Furthermore, when I echo the first element in the array it returns a value of 'a' rather than the actual array value.  This is probably just some stupid mistake, but it is baffling me.  Does anyone have any idea what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$sc2 = new ServiceCall($uri,null,false,false);
$sc2->makeCall();
$response = json_decode($sc2->getResponse(),true);
$tmp4 = var_export($response, true);
print_r($tmp4);
if(is_array($tmp4))
     echo "Tmp4 is an array";
else
     echo "Tmp4 is NOT an array";
```

Comment: What's the exact result of `print_r($tmp4);`?

Comment: Could you include the output of your `print_r($tmp4)`?

Comment: Must say: Sounds like you have a string `"Array"` ;)

Comment: Show us where and how you define `$tmp4`.

Comment: the result of print_r is: array ( 'RegStdClassLogService' => array ( 'request' => array ( 'method' => 'GET', 'resource' => '/583247982/20125/', ...etc...

Comment: What does `gettype($tmp4)` return?

Comment: It comes from a Json_decode function

Comment: that's not possible, having an array and is_array returning false, there must something else, show more code at your question!

Comment: gettype($tmp4) doesn't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: `json_decode()` doesn't return an array by default. Do you set the second parameter to `true`?

Comment: what does `var_dump($tmp4);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) is meant for persisting variables e.g. to files, thus it returns a string.

You can just use `$response` as your array, not `$tmp4`.